# For-each loop with null value in ArrayList

Tags: java

Consider this simple example :

```
List<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        integerArrayList.add(5);
        integerArrayList.add(6);
        integerArrayList.add(7);
        integerArrayList.add(null);
  

 for(int i=0;i<integerArrayList.size();i++){
         System.out.println(integerArrayList.get(i));
     }
```

This code will print `[5,6,7,null]` but, if I use `for-each` loop like this :

```
  for(int el : integerArrayList)
       System.out.println(el);
```

Then this code will throw `NullPointerException`, and I don't understand why.

As far as I know, for-each loop above is equivalent to this :

```
for (Iterator<Integer> i = integerArrayList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Integer item = i.next();
            System.out.println(item);
        }
```

But this loop doesn't throw `NullPointerException`!

I would like to know what is the explanation for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `null` can not be cast/unboxed to `int`, but you can just do `for (Integer el : ...) {`

Answer (score 3):

If you do `for(int el : integerArrayList)`, or e.g. `int x = integerArrayList.get(k)`, then you ["unbox"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) the `Integer` in the list to an `int`. And while an `Integer` may be `null`, and `int` *must* have a proper `int` value (even if this value is `0`), but not `null`.

To fix it, just use `Integer` instead of `int`, i.e.

```
for(Integer el : integerArrayList)
```